# Get property name in C#

Tags: c#

I have an object A, inside object A is object B, inside object B is object C, object C has a property called `Text`.

How can I get the full name of property `Text` when passing 'A.B.C.Text'? By full name I mean `A.B.C.Text` not the namespace.

Comment: `C` has no knowledge of its parent objects (from what you have told us so far) so you can't know. If the classes are nested this could work, but you generally don't want to do that.

Comment: Objects do not have the containing relationship as you describe, so the question cannot be answered.

Comment: also you cannot access A.B.C.Text

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) might give you a better explanation on how properties work.

I would suggest trying Google before posting something like this. Or at least post some code with a solution -you've- tried so far.

Comment: An example will be the ModelState object on MVC applications. When a property fails a validation, I get the name I'm mentioning inside the ModelState. How is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine (I got the class below from http://satalketo.com/2013/10/avoid-magic-strings/) :
This class is the one that retrieve the names:

```
public static class @string
    {
        private static string GetMemberName(Expression expression)
        {
            switch (expression.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression;
                    var supername = GetMemberName(memberExpression.Expression);

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(supername))
                        return memberExpression.Member.Name;

                    return String.Concat(supername, '.', memberExpression.Member.Name);

                case ExpressionType.Call:
                    var callExpression = (MethodCallExpression)expression;
                    return callExpression.Method.Name;

                case ExpressionType.Convert:
                    var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression;
                    return GetMemberName(unaryExpression.Operand);

                case ExpressionType.Constant:
                case ExpressionType.Parameter:
                    return String.Empty;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("The expression is not a member access or method call expression");
            }
        }

        public static string of<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
        {
            return GetMemberName(expression.Body);
        }

        public static string of(Expression<Action> expression)
        {
            return GetMemberName(expression.Body);
        }

        public static string of<T>()
        {
            return typeof(T).Name;
        }
    }
```

Then I define the classes:

```
class A
{
public A()
{
B = new B();
}
public B B { get; set; }
}

class B
{
public B()
{
C = new C();
}
public C C { get; set; }
}

class C
{
public String Text { get; set; }
}
```

finally, I just call the function created at the begging

```
A a = new A();
Console.Write(@string.of(() => a.B.C.Text));
```

//This prints a.B.C.Text

Answer (score 0):

Define your object like so:

```
class ObjectA
{
    public ObjectB ObjB { get; set; }
}

class ObjectB
{
    public ObjectC ObjC { get; set; }
}

class ObjectC
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
public static void GenericTester()
{
    var objA = new ObjectA {ObjB = new ObjectB {ObjC = new ObjectC {Text = "Hello"}}};

    Console.WriteLine(objA.ObjB.ObjC.Text);
}
```

Comment: that will print the property *value* not the property *name*